# jqGrid Events problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

i have scenario where i have to do the batch update like in save change i have send the update to the database from jgrid.

now, i am using the the array to store the updated data.

and on onafterupdate event i have to add the element to the array.
onafterupdate event is not working.

please, help me. How to use onafterupdate event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/css/base.css" />
</head>

<body>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript">

     var check=$retrivexml;
      alert(check);
      </script>-->
    <link href="../../Content/css/Style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/css/Style/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css"
        type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/css/Style/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css"
        media="screen" />
    <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../Content/css/Style/jqModal.css" />-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../Content/css/Style/datePicker.css" />-->
    <!--<link href="../../Content/css/Test/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
    <!--<link href="../../Content/css/Test/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->

    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/celledit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/JsonXml.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/grid.import.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/grid.base.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/grid.formedit.js"></script> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

     jQuery(document).ready( function() {

      var i=3;  
     var grid = jQuery("#test");
            var MyExportToXml = function (grid) {
                var dataFromGrid = {row: grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data') };
                var xmldata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>\n<rows>\n' +
                              xmlJsonClass.json2xml (dataFromGrid, '\t') + '</rows>';
                alert(xmldata);
            };


    var AddNewRow = function(id){

                      var datarow = {Consultant:"",Role:"",Task:"",SDate:"",EDate:"",
                                       Deliverables:"",Complete:""};
                      var lastsel2 = parseInt(id) + 1;
                      //debugger;
                      var su=jQuery("#test").addRowData(lastsel2, datarow, "last") ;
//                  if (su) { 
//                          jQuery('#test').editRow(lastsel2,true); 
//                     
//                           }  
                      };

     var lastsel3;
     var lastsel;
     jQuery("#test").jqGrid({
        url:'/Content/xml/user.xml',
        //url: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rows><page>aa</page><total>aa</total><records>aa</records><row id='1'><cell>1</cell><cell>False</cell><cell>Development</cell><cell>1-1-0001 0:00:00</cell><cell>1-1-0001 0:00:00</cell><cell>Management</cell><cell>False</cell></row></rows>,
     datatype: "xml",
        colNames:['Consultant','Project Role', 'Task', 'Start Date','End Date','Deliverables','Complete'],
        colModel:[
         {name:'Consultant',index:'Consultant', width:90, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"K:Kin;R:Rajesh;R:Renee;S:Sandeep"}},
         {name:'Role',index:'Role', width:80, align:"right",editable:true},
         {name:'Task',index:'Task', width:80, align:"right",editable:true},
         {name:'SDate',index:'SDate', width:90,editable:true},
         {name:'EDate',index:'EDate', width:90,editable:true},
         {name:'Deliverables',index:'Deliverables', width:200, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"25"}},
         {name:'Complete',index:'Complete', width:60, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Complete:Incomplete"}}  
        ],

//         onSelectRow:function(id){
//  lastsel=id;
//  //JQuery("#classTable").showCol("class_id"); 
//   
//  var data = jQuery("#test").getRowData(id).Consultant;  
//  alert(data);
//  //jQuery("#classTable").jqGrid('setGridParam',data); 
//  },

        rowNum:10,
        //rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#pagediv',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"Project Planning",
     forceFit : false,
     cellEdit: true,
     editurl:'clientArray',
     cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
     height: "100%", 

     ondblClickRow: function(id, iRow, iCol, e) { 
   alert(id);
     //getGridParam("records")
     //alert(selr);
     }, 



      //function(id, iRow, iCol, e) {alert(iRow);}, 

     afterEditCell: function (id,name,val,iRow,iCol){     

        if(name=='SDate') {
       jQuery("#"+iRow+"_SDate","#test").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});

      }

     if(name=='EDate') {
       jQuery("#"+iRow+"_EDate","#test").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
      }
     },


    });
    jQuery("#test").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagediv',{edit:false,add:false,del:false}).navButtonAdd('#pagediv', { caption:"Add", buttonicon :'ui-icon-circle-plus', title: "Add New Row",
       onClickButton: function() {debugger;
//       var last = jQuery('#test').jqGrid('getGridParam','records');                      
       var GridIds = grid.getDataIDs();
       var last= GridIds[GridIds.length -1 ];   
               AddNewRow (last);
           }
        });

    //grid[0].onafterupdate;
     grid[1].onafterupdate(function (){debugger;alert("Hellooooo")});

    $("#export").click(function(){
                MyExportToXml (grid);
            });


      });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="">
        <div align="center">
            <div id="pagediv">
            </div>
            <table id="test">
                <tr>
                    <td />
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" id="export" value="Export" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use cell editing the usage of [afterSaveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) seems me OK for your purpose.

Comment: @Oleg: IS there any event that fires editing the row my be like "aftereditRow".

Comment: When i am using the doubleclick to edit the column Calenender is not working because it on Aftereditcell event but i have to work it on cellclick event..

Comment: @Sandy: There are different events depend on editing mode which you use (**cell editing**, **inline editing**, **form editing**). You use `cellEdit: true`, so cell editing. For cell editing is `afterSaveCell` is the correct place to do something after the cell is modified. You can remove `cellEdit:true` and call `editRow` for example directly after inserting of the empty row. Then you should use `succesfunc`, `errorfunc` and `aftersavefunc` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) to save the data or remove the new empty row in case of an error.

Comment: @Sandy: for **inline editing** the function `aftersavefunc` is what you need.

Comment: @Oleg: I m using the afterSaveCell event but it not ger fired in my code..   Below is my code

Comment: @Sandy: Please be careful. The function `afterSaveCell` is **NOT** an event of jqGrid. To use this you have to use **additional *aftersavefunc* parameter** of `editRow`. I've written this in my previous comment.